# ERRO URL codeigniter3 access

Tags: codeigniter-3

My application is accessed by the port number in the url, example: http://localhost:8056/site/ . Loads the site normally and all. When accessing a link, example http://localhost:8056/site/user/view, does not direct to correct application, any link from the site redirects to a standard address http://localhost:8056/dashboard/

In codeigniter3 the variable `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8056/site/';` I did not understand why the redirect to any default url that has not been defined and is not used in the system. the system has to respect the base url reported in `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8056/autoescolaonline/';`

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess and vhost config for any redirect/rewrite rules?  What is at `/dashboard`, is it part of your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file (where your application folder is)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/index.php/$1 [L]
```